# Storm message timeout works improperly

Tags: apache-storm

I found the following when I used the debug mode. TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS is set to 90s. Spout should not get more than 90s from sending to getting a fail message, but why is 135s in the log?

```
2019-05-14 16:53:12.037 o.a.s.s.CheckpointSpout Thread-13-$checkpointspout-executor[1 1] [DEBUG] Current state CheckPointState{txid=7, state=COMMITTING}, emitting txid 7, action COMMIT
2019-05-14 16:55:27.097 o.a.s.s.CheckpointSpout Thread-13-$checkpointspout-executor[1 1] [DEBUG] Got fail with msgid 7
2019-05-14 16:55:27.097 o.a.s.s.CheckpointSpout Thread-13-$checkpointspout-executor[1 1] [DEBUG] Checkpoint failed, will trigger recovery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message timeout is not a hard limit. The messages may take up to 2x the timeout to actually time out. This is due to a performance optimization, where instead of timing out tuples every second, we have two buckets. When a tuple is created, it gets put into bucket 1. Once the timeout has passed, we rotate all bucket 1 tuples into bucket 2, and fail all bucket 2 tuples. This lets us guarantee that a tuple gets at least the full message timeout to complete, while also being cheap to compute.

Comment: According to the default RotatingMap, there are 3 buckets. How long can the maximum timeout be reached? Is it 2 times what you said?

Comment: There are two buckets in the use of RotatingMap I'm referring to https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.2.3/storm-core/src/clj/org/apache/storm/daemon/executor.clj#L512. Yes, the max timeout is twice what you set.